# Angular FormBuilder not resetting arrays

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

After every attempt of saving the items selected, I would like for that list to be cleared or empty. For example, a user selected one item - selects save. In the console you will view that object that you have selected. Now if you select the other item and select save, you will still see the previous item that was selected within the console. It would be best if after every save, the array was cleared.

First save:

```
selectedMessages
Array(1)
{messageID: 222, message: "text"}
```

Second Save:

```
selectedMessages
Array(2)
{messageID: 222, message: "text"}
{messageID: 331, message: "text Two"}
```

component.ts

```
rMessages: Message[] = [];
  aMessages: Message[] = [];


constructor( 
  public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
  ) { 
    this.messageForm = formBuilder.group({
      selectedMessages: this.formBuilder.array([])
    })
   }
    save(form){
    console.log(form.value.selectedMessages)
    }

select(rmessage:Message, isChecked: boolean){
    const selectedMessages = <FormArray>this.messageForm.controls.selectedMessages;
    if(isChecked) {
      selectedMessages.push(new FormControl(rmessage));  
    } else {
      let index = selectedMessages.controls.findIndex(x => x.value.messageID == rmessage.messageID);
      selectedMessages.removeAt(index);
    }
  }
buildChecked() {
    const arr = this.rMessages.map(message => {
      console.log(this.formBuilder.control(message.messageID))
      return this.formBuilder.control(message.messageID)
    });
    return this.formBuilder.array(arr);
  }
```

HTML

```
<form [formGroup]="messageForm" (ngSubmit)="save(messageForm)">
    <ion-list active text-wrap *ngSwitchCase="'received'" >
      <div class="items"> 

    <ion-item *ngFor="let rmessage of rMessages; index as i">
        <ion-label>
          {{rmessage.message}}
        </ion-label>
        <ion-checkbox (ionChange)="select(rmessage, $event.checked)" value="rmessage"></ion-checkbox>
    </ion-item>

      </div>
        <button ion-button full type="submit"  style="font-size:1.8rem">save</button>
    </ion-list>
  </form>
```

Updated - w/ reset not functioning. getting null.

```
rMessages: Message[] = [];
      aMessages: Message[] = [];


    constructor( 
      public formBuilder: FormBuilder,
      ) { 
        this.messageForm = formBuilder.group({
          selectedMessages: this.formBuilder.array([])
        })
       }
        save(form){
this.rMessages = this.rMessages.filter((resultTwo) => {
      return !form.value.receivedMessages.find((resultOne) => {

        return resultTwo.messageID === resultOne.messageID
      })
    })
       this.aMessages = this.aMessages.concat(form.value.receivedMessages.filter((resultOne) => {
        console.log(resultOne, 'results')

        return resultOne

    }))
        this.messageForm.reset()
        }

    select(rmessage:Message, isChecked: boolean){
        const selectedMessages = <FormArray>this.messageForm.controls.selectedMessages;
        if(isChecked) {
          selectedMessages.push(new FormControl(rmessage));  
        } else {
          let index = selectedMessages.controls.findIndex(x => x.value.messageID == rmessage.messageID);
          selectedMessages.removeAt(index);
        }
      }
    buildChecked() {
        const arr = this.rMessages.map(message => {
          console.log(this.formBuilder.control(message.messageID))
          return this.formBuilder.control(message.messageID)
        });
        return this.formBuilder.array(arr);
      }
```

Comment: what's the point of having an array if you only ever put one element in it?

Answer (score 1):

you can clear the form

```
this.messageForm.reset()
```

and the text will remain in the console

Comment: Getting a null value for the message when selecting save. It seems reset makes my objects undefined

Comment: can you update your post with the relevant code? make sure you call reset after you log/get the value

Comment: you could be missing something with all the map operators. can you try in the save method commenting all your code at and only logging the input and then doing reset? start there, if it logged before it would still log with reset

Answer (score 0):

When you want clear the array and set it as empty, use `setControl()`

```
this.messageForm.setControl('selectedMessages', this.formBuilder.array([]))
```

this will replace your existing array.